# Facing an issue while executing the unit test cases

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library, infragistics, ignite-ui

I want some clarification on the IgrDataGrid

Currently we are using this version of Infragistics.

```
"igniteui-react": "18.4.0",
  "igniteui-react-charts": "18.4.0",
  "igniteui-react-core": "18.4.0",
  "igniteui-react-excel": "18.4.0",
  "igniteui-react-grids": "18.4.0",
  "igniteui-react-inputs": "18.4.0",
  "igniteui-react-layouts": "18.4.0",
  "igniteui-webcomponents": "4.6.0",
```

and this are the version that we are using for unit test cases. Earlier it was working fine, but may be this issue is there with the new version of Infragistics grid.

```
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "6.1.5",
  "@testing-library/react": "14.1.2",
  "@types/jest": "29.5.11",
 "jest": "29.7.0",
  "jest-environment-jsdom": "29.7.0",
 "ts-jest": "29.1.1",
```

While executing the unit test cases we are getting an issue regarding the igniteUI. Please refer the attached screenshot for the reference.
[image]

Please refer the above mentioned point and suggest the best approach to resolve the issue.